# Как расположить div'ы на одной строке?

Tags: html, css

Я не буду ничего говорить, просто посмотрите на картинку. Написал свойство `float: right;` и ужаснулся от увиденного. Почему так произошло, и как сделать этот блок на одной строке с остальными?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.hat {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.hat .container .logotype {
  margin: 1.75% 2.14%;
  float: left;
}

.hat .container .search {
  width: 436px;
  height: 33px;
  margin: 2.39% auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hat .container .search input {
  width: 436px;
  height: 33px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: absolute;
}

.hat .container .search button {
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.basket_but {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="hat">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="logotype" alt="Aditu">
    </a>

    <div class="search">
      <input type="text">
      <button><img src="images/lupa.png" alt="lupa"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="basket_but">
      <p>$0</p>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```css
.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="hat">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logotype" alt="Aditu">
      </a>

      <div class="search">
        <input type="text">
        <button><img src="images/lupa.png" alt="lupa"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="basket_but">
        <p>$0</p>

        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

И зачем Вы плодите темы? Вы же уже задавали подобный вопрос

Comment: "И зачем Вы плодите темы?" Ничего. С утра народ злой бывает - проснутся, навтыкают минусов))

Comment: Не помогло. Объекты просто сдвинулись в один угол (слева) и все.

Comment: Добавьте скрин результата в пост, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите расположить элемент справа при помощи `float: right`, то этот элемент должен находиться в html выше того элемента, справа от которого должен быть.

```css
.float {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

/* Фикс от флоатов */
.float::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.float > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.float .left {
  background: red;
}

.float .right {
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="float">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

---

Но лучше и проще использовать технологию [**Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) или [**Grid Layout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

Вариант на **flex**

```css
.float {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

.float > div {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.float .left {
  background: red;
}

.float .right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="float">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, для выравнивания элементов хорошо подходит flex-вёрстка.

Вот решение Вашего примера:

html-разметка:

```
<div class="hat">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png" class="logotype" alt="Aditu">
        </a>

        <div class="search">
            <input type="text">
            <button><img src="images/lupa.png" alt="lupa"></button>
        </div>

        <div class="basket_but">
            <p class="price">$0</p>

            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/basket.png" alt="basket">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот CSS-правила:

```
 .container{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow:flow wrap;
      justify-content:space-between;
      width:50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .basket_but{
      display:flex;
      flex-flow:flow wrap;
      justify-content:space-between;
    }

    .price{
      width:50%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.basket_but{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]